# innerhtml message if no elements in filter

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html

In my project I'm using the script MixItUp which is good for filtering and sorting elements. In my case I'm using data from xml files.

I would like a message to display in innerhtml if filtering results in no elements. I have tried to accomplish this but it isn't very smooth.

My project can be seen here: http://www.halfmen.dk/2017/statistics.php

This is the script which display the 'no show' message:

```
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(function(){
            $('#miucontainer').on('mixEnd', function(e,state){
                $('.noposts').html(state.totalShow==0?'Ingen spillere i denne kategori':'');
            });
        });
    </script>
```

If you for instance click the button with the 2015-label and afterwards click on 2016 you will see the lack of smoothness.

Any suggestions would be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like jQuery can't handle the requests fast enough.

You can try clearing the animation queue's by calling `.clearQueue()` see https://api.jquery.com/clearQueue/

Or maybe even add an articial delay between the animations to validate the data and prepare it before the animation takes places.